# Facing ECONNREFUSED error while connecting to MySQL database (127.0.0.1:3306)

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

I'm encountering an ECONNREFUSED error when attempting to connect to my MySQL database using Node.js. I've configured my connection to use the address '127.0.0.1' and port '3306', but the connection is being refused. Here's a snippet of my code:
this error is coming when i try to deploy my project on render.com

my backend code is :

```
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

app.listen(8000, (req, res) => {
  console.log("connected to backend");
});

const db = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 10,
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "*****",
  database: "expense",
  debug: false,
});

db.getConnection((err, connection) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error("Error connecting to database: " + err.stack);
    return;
  }
  console.log("Connected to database with threadId: " + connection.threadId);
  connection.release();
});

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const q = "SELECT * FROM expenses";
  db.query(q, (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.json(err);
    if (data) return res.json(data);
  });
});

app.post("/expenses", (req, res) => {
  const q = "INSERT INTO expenses (`text`, `amount`, `type`) VALUES (?)";
  const values = [req.body.text, req.body.amount, req.body.type];

  db.query(q, [values], (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.json(err);
    return res.json("expense created successfully");
  });
});

app.delete("/expenses/:id", (req, res) => {
  const expenseId = req.params.id;
  const q = "DELETE FROM expenses WHERE id = ?";

  db.query(q, [expenseId], (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.json(err);
    return res.json("expense deleted successfully");
  });
});

app.put("/expenses/:id", (req, res) => {
  const expenseId = req.params.id;
  const q =
    "UPDATE expenses SET `text`=? , `amount`= ? , `type` = ? WHERE id = ?";
  const values = [req.body.text, req.body.amount, req.body.type];

  db.query(q, [...values, expenseId], (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.json(err);
    return res.json("expense updated successfully");
  });
});
```

I tried all the things like :
Ensured MySQL service was running and listening on port 3306.
Attempted connection using both TCP/IP and Unix sockets.
Verified the MySQL user permissions and access to the database.
Checked the MySQL configuration file (my.cnf) for socket path.
Reviewed system logs for any relevant error messages.
Tested the setup locally to isolate the issue.

Comment: Please, NEVER EVER EVER share whatever password you are using in a **public forum**.

Comment: Make sure your MySQL server is up and running. Also, verify connection to the database using a client tool like `mysql` or MySQL Workbench. If your database is running then your code `db.getConnection((err, connection) => {` should show a message of successful connection on starting the app.

Comment: Your connection looks fine. If you only experience this problem when you try to deploy on render.com please bear in mind that although you are using `localhost` as the host it assumes your app and database are on the same server. This works perfectly if running on you local machine. However, if your mysql instance is hosted on another server on render.com then you may need to pass in the DNS name or IP address to get connected.

Comment: @jQueeny as you said i have updated the port number provided by the render but now below mentioned error is coming.
{"code":"PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR","fatal":false}

Comment: The `hostname` needs to be an ip address, dns name or one of those with the port if different from 3306. For example `192.168.1.5` or `myapp.example.com`. Passing lust a port number in would achieve anything.